# evidence of any particular law of nature?

Tags: grammar

> **Hume first of all analysed the evidence that we have that any
> particular law of nature holds**. For something to be accepted as a law
> of nature – for instance, that no one ever rises from the dead – there
> must be the maximum possible amount of evidence confirming it.

Philosophy : The basics

In the bold text, did the author mean that Hume analysed the evidence of any particular law of nature? I am so confused to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Well philosophy is confusing, and while Hume is easier to follow than (for example) Kant, it is hard for a native speaker also. Perhaps you could read up on Hume in your native language.

Hume was interested in how we can claim to "know" a particular law of nature. He studied the general process of getting evidence of any law of nature.

The example is helpful. How do we know that "people never rise from the dead" how much evidence is required to be certain of this fact?  This fact is a particular law of nature. The evidence is all those people who have died and not risen from the dead. What would be enough evidence?

(The conclusion is that we can never get enough evidence to prove a general fact by observing specific examples, which challenges the basis of science... But also that we can never get enough evidence for the existence of miracles, which challenges a basis of religion)

Comment: Good answer, James. Mine's less useful but I'll leave it and hope it's complementary.

Comment: @James K: could you rewrite the bold text in a way it's easier to understand. I really don't understand the meaning of the word "hold" here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've understood it correctly.

The relevant meaning of '"holds" is:

> *3.3 (of an argument or theory) be logical, consistent, or convincing.
>
> ‘this basic argument holds for almost any economic model of
> competition’*

([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hold))

We can leave out the first "that" and say,

Hume first of all analysed the evidence we have that any particular law of nature is logical, consistent, or convincing.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the word hold mean "contain"